# search emacs buffer like helm grep?

Tags: emacs, buffer, emacs-helm

You can search for word list ('hello', 'world') by typing `world <space> hello` in helm-grep

I currently use ido for buffer switching, and I have to type `world C-<space> hello` to filter by two words.

Is there a buffer switch mode which offer the filtering by words separated by just a `space`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```lisp
(defun my-ido-setup-hook ()
  (define-key
      ido-buffer-completion-map
      " "
    'ido-restrict-to-matches))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'my-ido-setup-hook)
```

Comment: christ.. Should have asked this earlier! Thanks abo-abo. They should have made this default..